# Choosing a boxing weight class

Tags: training, boxing

Boxers compete within weight classes that specify the range within which a boxer's body-weight may lie. But boxers (particularly those close to a weight class boundary) can presumably increase or decrease their weight to fall in at least two different classes.

My question has the following parts:

- what principles do a boxer/trainer use to determine which weight class to aim for? Do boxers tend to aim to loose weight and make the class below, or beef-up to enter the higher weight class?
- what is the rationale behind this?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the perfect is to be right below the Upper limit for a certain weight category. Thus all your opponents will weight less so you can use your weight for the advantages like taking hits/giving k.o.'s and especially clinching.

For every boxer it is important to keep balance between muscle weight and speed. Usually if you gain a lot of weight (muscle weight of course) you are getting slower. And vice Versa.

All this is very simplified and depends where an individual boxer can show the highest results.